# How can I do a Directory Listing of ebsites with Ez?

Tags: ezpublish

I need to do a specific task with Ez Publish but I don't have a clue on how to do it.

What I need to do is a list of Websites(Website directory). I will need to add basically two kinds of data:

- Website Name
- URL of the website

Then, when I click in the website link it will redirect to a page where I have the IFRAME with the link(URL of the website).

Can someone give me a clue about how to do this with Ez Publish? I'm a beginner.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said anything about where you're getting the list from, so I assume you have the list already and just want to know the correct way to input this type of content.
Login to the site admin area, browse to the part of the site you want the list to be at (usually a folder). You'll be adding content items of type 'link' below the folder.
Select the 'Link' content type and click on the 'Create' here button. Enter the content (including the link URL to the page containing the IFRAME) then send for publishing.
I'm assuming the sites are your own, since many sites now take steps to prevent others placing their page in an IFRAME.
If you want this page to not just link to the iframe page, but to actually display the iframe content, then you'll need to override the default link template (copy it and tell eZ to use your version instead) and add a bit of html for the IFRAME.

If you're the main user imputing this content, you could also just allow eZ to accept literal HTML in the main description text areas (XML Block) and just paste in your IFRAME html. Ugly but quick to set-up.
You should be able to find many examples of entering literal html at the community web forums http://share.ez.no/forums

Comment: Maybe too complicated... And you're overriding an existing class with its proper behaviour. Why not creating a new class with dedicated template ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a specific class for that with the two fields you need.

One for the name and another one with the URL.

Then you'll just have to make an override of `node/view/full.tpl` for your new class Where you will display the name and an iframe with URL that have been typped in your class instance.